# Pandas multi index Dataframe - Select and remove

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help with cleaning a Dataframe that has multi index.

it looks something like this

```
                   cost
location season 
Thorp park  autumn £12
            srping £13
            summer £22
Sea life centre  summer  £34
                 spring  £43
Alton towers     and so on.............
```

location and season are index columns. I want to go through the data and remove any locations that don't have "season" values of all three seasons. So "Sea life centre" should be removed.

Can anyone help me with this?

Also another question, my dataframe was created from a groupby command and doesn't have a column name for the "cost" column. Is this normal? There are values in the column, just no header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**
`groupby` + `count`. You can use the result to index your dataframe.

```
df

     col
a 1    0
  2    1
b 1    3
  2    4
  3    5
c 2    7
  3    8

v = df.groupby(level=0).transform('count').values
df = df[v == 3]

df

     col
b 1    3
  2    4
  3    5
```

---

**Option 2**
`groupby` + `filter`. This is [Paul H's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47239494/pandas-multi-index-dataframe-select-and-remove/47239563?noredirect=1#comment81429606_47239563), will remove if he wants to post.

```
df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda g: g.count() == 3)

     col
b 1    3
  2    4
  3    5
```

Comment: would `df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda g: g.count() != 3)` have the same effect?

Comment: Thanks Paul, is there a way to reverse your suggestion. This gives the values where count is not 3. I want these to be removed from my dataframe.  I tries this df.groupby(level=0).filter(lambda g: g.count() = 3) but this doesn't work

Comment: @SANM2009 See my answer, I've given you two options, both do what you want.

Comment: @SANM2009 obviously, there is. i recommend you get a little more familiar with python syntax. the tricky part for me is remembering if `filter` removes or keeps the groups that match condition. based on the answer, it keeps.

Comment: @PaulH yep, based on observations, `GroupBy.filter` works exactly as python's builtin `filter` would.

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Any idea why this doesn't change the column title: df.rename(columns = {0:'a name'}, inplace=True)

Comment: you don't have a column whose label is `0`

Comment: @SANM2009 Idk what `0` is, but try: `df = df.rename(columns = {df.columns[0]:'a name'})`

Comment: got it working. I was working with a series (I hadn't declared it to a dataframe). All sorted. I am very new with Python and dam it is crazy. lol

Comment: @SANM2009 Don't forget to accept an answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: Thanks all, I will mark it answered. Just a question to understand,what is g?  is g a reserved word for groupby results?

Comment: @SANM2009 It's a lambda variable. It can be anything you want.

Comment: Thanks. Finally, I can't find mark as answer button?

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**
Thinking outside the box...

```
df.drop(df.count(level=0).col[lambda x: x < 3].index)

     col
b 1    3
  2    4
  3    5
```

Same thing with a little more robustness because I'm not depending on values in a column.

```
df.drop(df.index.to_series().count(level=0).loc[lambda x: x < 3].index)

     col
b 1    3
  2    4
  3    5
```

---

**Option 2**
Robustify for general case with undetermined number of seasons.
This uses Pandas version 0.21's `groupby.pipe` method

```
df.groupby(level=0).pipe(lambda g: g.filter(lambda d: len(d) == g.size().max()))

     col
b 1    3
  2    4
  3    5
```

Comment: what's being passed to the inner lambda?

Comment: @PaulH those are the grouped dataframes.

Comment: OK, and the entire `groupby` object is feed to the outer lambda?